# How to make hover work on none-adjacent nor child element

Tags: css, hover

I am trying to make a div change its position when the user is hovering another div. The div that triggers the move is not parent nor adjecent to the div that shall move. Can this be done with css or do I need to go for js?

Here is the code:

```css
.container{
  display: inline-block;
}

.redOnTop{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.smallBlueBehind{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left: -55px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transition: 1s;
    z-index: -10;
}

#redLeft:hover + #blueLeft{
    transition: 1s;
    left: -5px;
}

#showingArea{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    //overflow: hidden;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    left: -5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

//------------------------------ HOW TO WRITE HERE!
#redRight:hover #blueRight{
    transition: 1s;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="redOnTop" id="redLeft">
    </div>
    <div class="smallBlueBehind" id="blueLeft">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="redOnTop" id="redRight">
    </div>

    <div id="showingArea">
        <div class="smallBlueBehind" id="blueRight">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I want the right blue square slide out from under the red square and end up in the black-bordered box when hovering said red square. Same as the left one.. only difference is that I want it inside the black box.

[Here is a codepen if someone likes that better.](https://codepen.io/The_Real_Brainmaniac/pen/JEOEme)

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Here i see nether a red square nor a blue square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use adjacent selector and then target the blue rectangle...

```
#redRight:hover + #showingArea #blueRight{
    transition: 1s;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
.redOnTop {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.smallBlueBehind {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: -55px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  transition: 1s;
  z-index: -10;
}
#redLeft:hover + #blueLeft {
  transition: 1s;
  left: -5px;
}
#showingArea {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  //overflow: hidden;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  left: -5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#redRight:hover + #showingArea #blueRight {
  transition: 1s;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="redOnTop" id="redLeft">
  </div>
  <div class="smallBlueBehind" id="blueLeft">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="redOnTop" id="redRight">
  </div>

  <div id="showingArea">
    <div class="smallBlueBehind" id="blueRight">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/OWOmad)

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. When removing the border and un-comment overflow:hidden - this code now allows for hiding the blue sliding rectangle under the redsquare with opacity.